# Tags edits and a question about excerpts

Tags: discussion

By a review on the tags lists, we see that some of the tags do not have any wiki or excerpts. I just want to know, which one is more prefered, a tag without any wiki or excerpt; or a tag with a wiki excerpt that just says "{topic}: this tag is for questions about {topic}" is better than nothing?

Answer (score 2):

A tag wiki that does not add any meaningful information is not helpful.

An empty tag wiki at least signals that somebody should write a meaningful tag wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Some words have a few different meanings or contexts.

IMHO a tag wiki is for disambiguating them, e.g. by providing synonyms or longer description.

Don't add "This tag is about..." (Even "Questions on..." may be redundant.). See [tags from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) as a good example.

Comment: I have never seen [tags from Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tags); they are good examples indeed.