# How to use Stack Exchange answers in the Tags wiki?

Tags: discussion, tags

It is sometimes an answer to a question on academia stack exchange website is perfect to be put on the wiki of a tag. Is it a good idea to use such answers in wiki? If your answer is positive, how should it be cited? Is the example bellow enough or some citation note should be added?

---

According to an answer on Academia Stack Exchange, [Question Title]:

> A paragraph from an answer to that question is block quoted here.

---

The answer to this question may help to two other questions about tags.

- [Tag excerpts and wikis, should citations be fully addresses?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/tag-excerpts-and-wikis-should-citations-be-fully-addresses?rq=1)
- [Tags edits and a question about excerpts](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1101/tags-edits-and-a-question-about-excerpts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with: as far as I know, `tag wiki excerpts` are not places to share comprehensive information about subjects.
It is a short description so that when people add tags to a question, they can judge wether the tag is appropriate (e.g. that [masters](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masters) is about *studies leading to M.Sc.*, not - *the best and the brightest* ;)).

Consequently, I find most of you edits (albeit well-intended) providing extraneous information.

Especially it is not their place to judge any topic, or provide too much of extra information and distracting from the short, concise definition (1-2 sentences long).

As a short example, IMHO the current version of [united-states](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) is better:

> Topics specific to the United States.

In your edit there is a lot of repeatings (this site is about academia, so there is no need to add clauses about education and academia to each tag; on the other had, the last sentence "Use this tag..." may be beneficial):

> Questions specifically about universities and academic institutes in
>   the United States of America and higher education at this country. Use
>   this tag alongside other tags to mention that your question is related
>   to this country.

For the longer `tag wiki` - I don't know if it is that useful and worth spending time on it. In any case:

- If do verbatim copy form Wikipedia, use `>` (and provide a link to a particular Wikipedia page).
- If it is only tangentially based on Wikipedia, it is so general knowledge stuff that should not attributed at all.

Comment: Could you please show me one or two more examples from my edits? I want to become more aware and understand your professional attitude. [I also want to thank you so much for your precise answer, it was great, well organized, exactly showed me the weaknesses of my edits.]

Comment: Also it would be great if you take a look at these questions too: [Tag excerpts and wikis, should citations be fully addresses?](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1104/tag-excerpts-and-wikis-should-citations-be-fully-addresses?rq=1) and [Tags edits and a question about excerpts](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1101/tags-edits-and-a-question-about-excerpts)

Comment: @Parsa Edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I think that a good excerpt should be something  between the first and the second excerpts which you have in your quotation. As I understand, something in two or three short sentences, describing the tag, no judgment and no extra information. The extra information goes into the second part, wiki.

Comment: Do you mean that we may not need this sentence that exists in wiki of many tags in newer wikis `Note : This tag wiki has content adapted from Wikipedia, used under the CC-BY-SA 3.0 license.` and a `>` with a link to a particular Wikipedia page is enough? The same as this tag: [phd](http://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/phd/info)?

Comment: @Parsa _IMHO_ for such a short thing as a `tag wiki`, when we explicitly link to Wikipedia, this note is too formal.

Comment: ...especially as you can quote any content, even copyrighted (e.g. `as stated by Microsoft, Windows Vista is... "[short quotation]"`). You don't copy whole Wikipedia pages or anything.

Comment: What do you mean by `IMHO`?

Comment: "In my humble opinion": http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IMHO, http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=in+my+humble+opinion

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I actually disagree with the example you gave. "Topics specific to the United States" does not help anyone understand whether their use of the tag is appropriate, while the more verbose version does.

Comment: @ff524 You may be right, and maybe it was not the best example. My point was that appending words that are a requirement on Academia.SE (i.e. that the topic is related to academia, higher education etc) to every question is, IMHO, counterproductive.

Comment: I noticed that many of the off-topic questions that have nothing to do with academia at all are tagged with only "country" and/or "discipline" tags. so I think for these tags, specifying how they are used in the context of academia might be helpful.